# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Nginx when trying to use react application?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a react application which runs on port 3000. I can access this fine by the IP address and using :3000, however when I try to access the site via the URL, I get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

I've asked the guys who sold me the app, but they tell me the issue is with Cloudflare. The thing is, I don't use cloudflare. I used to some time ago, but my DNS points straight to the server.

I have a single VPS and I only host this one site on it.

The default settings (which I don't know if you will need to help) it the default settings when I installed Nginx.

My current config file for 'rentfromowner' looks like this:

```
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream rentfromowner {
    server 159.65.88.218:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {   
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name rentfromowner.co.uk www.rentfromowner.co.uk;
    return 301 https:/rentfromowner.co.uk$request_uri;
}

 server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 default_server ssl;
    server_name rentfromowner.co.uk www.rentfromowner.co.uk;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/rentfromowner.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/rentfromowner.co.uk.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://www.rentfromowner.co.uk:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      return 301 http://www.rentfromowner.co.uk;
}

 }
```

Can anyone help me understand why it's redirecting and not working because the guys told me this is correct - but I don't think it can be?

Because it's not using port 80 for the app etc - then I have never done anything like this before so I'm trying to learn as much as I can - but I just cant figure it out at all.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `location /` block, once you do the proxy stuff, you should not `return 301 ...`, that's what is causing the eternal redirect. Just remove that line and let the proxy handle the request.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but which line(s) do I need to remove. Thanks for your help with this Pavel!!!

Comment: @Paul added an image to illustrate: simply remove that `return 301 ...` line, you don't need it there.

Comment: @Paul Glad I could help, `nginx` can be really frustrating sometimes. If my answer solved your problem completely, do you mind accepting it? Cheers ;)

Comment: Done ;o) Thank you!